# Removal at index from doubly linked list java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Here is the beginning of the class if it helps at all. I'm trying to write a method to remove an element from a specific index in the doubly linked list. I'm not sure if I'm remotely on the right path but this is what i've done and I'm getting a NullPointerException at:

prevNode.next = nextNode;

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
    Node start;
    Node end;
    int length;

public DoublyLinkedList() {
    this.start = null;
    this.end = null;
    this.length = 0;
}


public void removeAtIndex(int index) {
    Node currentNode = start;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (index < 0 || index > length) {
            System.out.println("The index is out of bounds");
            return;
        } else if (currentNode == null) {
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
            return;
        } else if (i == index - 1) {
            Node nextNode = currentNode.next;
            Node prevNode = currentNode.prev;
            prevNode.next = nextNode;
            nextNode.prev = prevNode;
            return;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your full code?

Answer (score 0):

With your flow, it is return null because the currentNode is null at first.
Let's take a look at your code. (I guess you've started programing, right :P)

1. Move out the check IndexOutOfBounds from the for, nothing to do with for loop here.
2. Your idea about remove item at i by set pre node linked to next node, It is OK, and i see your code is fine.
3. I hope that you have implemented the **addNode** to increase the **length**, because it will not go into the for loop.

Once again, check out your code and clear your mind. Many return is not really good.

Comment: I have a similar problem, do you think you can help me out. I've been searching everywhere on the internet, through my books and I'm getting nowhere.